# Android Progress Bar is not dismissed

Tags: android

I am using Progress Dialog to show progress while loading web page, but sometimes it does not work properly. Progress Dialog never get dismissed though page is loaded.

I have added Progress Bar like this

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    //Added progress dialog
}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if(progressdialog.isShowing())
       progressdialog.dismiss(); //Dismissed the progress, but sometimes never dismiss it
}
```

Comment: Put a log statement in to make sure that `dismiss()` is being called: `Log.d("MyApp", "dismiss() was called");`

Comment: make sure that the flow is entering the function onPageFinished

Answer (score 1):

android_dev , Use a handler

```
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    { 
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
     if(progressdialog.isShowing() || progressdialog!=null)
     progressdialog.dismiss();
     progressdialog=null;
      }
    }
```

& you are done!

Comment: onPageFinished function is called twice, first time when page loaded it dismisses the progress dialog and for the second time, the condition becomes false and dismiss is never called. This case is happens with https:// only . How should i solve this please tell me